# Parser for CSV with headers on multiple lines using Java

Tags: java, csv

Is there a Java *library* that would allow me to parse *CSV* files that have headers defined on multiple lines? Here's an example for such a *CSV* :

**$ID$,$Customer$**

```
Cust1, Jack

Cust2 , Rose
```

**$Name$,$Location$**

```
Sherlock,London

Clouseau,Paris
```

The "$" symbol indicates the presence of headers on that line, and the values in subsequent rows map to these headers.

Comment: Most CSV parsers will just parse the lines. It's up to you to interpret the first line as a header. Or not. So it's up to you to recognize a second header too.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your particular use case, but you can simply read all rows and check when a header row appears.

[univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) allows you to handle this without any trouble.

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(new File("/path/to/your.csv")));
for(String[] row : allRows){
     if(isHeaderRow(row)){ // isHeaderRow() would test whether each element is enclosed within $
          // do stuff to "switch" to a new header row.
     } else {
          // do stuff
     }
}
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Comment: Got the 1Gb csv file both with unescaped quotes and multi-line values. Much thanks to @jeronimo-backes for his [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial). Small memory footprint, flexible settings, friendly support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JEzCSV](https://github.com/Yiao/JEzCSV) for Parsing the fichier csv with anytype dimiliter that you want